# string not printing properly in C

Tags: c

I am encountering a problem while printing out a string using a while loop in a standalone function.

I have the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int pword(char *);
int main() {
    char s[] = "Alice";
    pword(s);
    return 0;
}

int pword(char *s) {
    while(*s!='\0') {
        printf("%s", s);
        s++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

This is printing: **Aliceliceicecee**.

Comment: Are you supposed to print one *character* at a time in the loop? Think a little bit about what the `"%s"` format means, and how to get a single character from a pointer.

Comment: You aim `printf()` at whatever `s` is pointing to, and tell the function to "print everything up to but not including the null terminator" (that is what the `%s` in the format string means). Which `printf()` obediently does. Then you increment `s`, making it point at the next character in the string, and repeat the process. ;-) Remember: The computer always does *exactly* what you tell it to. Try `puts()` / `fputs()` to print the whole string, or `putchar()` / `fputc()` to print individual characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you're printing the *offseted* word each time, instead of the character.

Try changing (for instance)

```
printf("%s", s);
```

by

```
printf("%c", *s);
```

or since you don't really need formatting, use

```
putchar(*s);
```

(all this means that you're basically rewriting `puts` with a loop. So if no further processing is required on the characters, maybe you should just stick with standard functions)

Comment: Terribly sorry. New to this site. Didn't mean to disrespect anyone! I've accepted it!

Answer (score 2):

`%s` means expect a `const char *` argument

`%c` means expect a character argument. The character argument is printed. Null characters are ignored;

You are looking for later one.

More info on `%s`: The argument is taken to be a string (character pointer), and characters from the string
are printed until a null character or until the number of characters indicated by the
precision specification is reached; however, if the precision is 0 or missing, all characters up to a null are printed;

Answer (score 1):

Seeing no answer explained what exactly was going on, here is what you are actually doing:

```
int pword(char *s) {      /* s = "Alice" (s is a char* that holds the address of "Alice" string)*/
    while(*s!='\0') {     /* check if the first char pointed to by s != '\0' */
    printf("%s", s);      /* print the string that start at s*/
    s++;                  /* move s (the char pointer) 1 step forward*/
  }                       /* s points to "lice" -> "ice" -> "ce" -> "e" */
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

In order to print the string "Alice" you could have just used `printf("%s", s);` as it would take the address pointed to by `s`, where "Alice" is stored, and print it until reaching *null-terminator* (`'\0'`).

If you want to use a loop and print `char` by `char`, you should have used `printf("%c", *s);`. Using `%c` is meant for printing `char` where `%s` is for printing strings. Another thing to note is the `s` vs `*s`, where the former is a `char* (pointer to char)` that can hold number of consecutive `char`s, and the later (`*s)`is `*(char*)` i.e. dereferenced `char*`, that holds a single `char`.

To sum up:

print `char` by `char`

```
int pword(char *s) {
    while(*s!='\0') {
    printf("%c", *s);
    s++;
  }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

print the whole string at once

```
int pword(char *s) {
    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print character by character, you should use `*s` in the printf statement like below.

```
  #include <stdio.h>
    int pword(char *);
    int main() {
        char s[] = "Alice";
        pword(s);
        return 0;
    }

    int pword(char *s) {
        while(*s!='\0') {
        printf("%c", *s);
        s++;
      }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: This website is not *solve my code*, but more like *give me explained answer on my question*.